# Containerd.io depends libseccomp2

Tags: docker, debian-buster

Hi I'm trying to install docker in my Debian 10 computer and I have a few problems trying to install containerd.io service.

When I'm trying to install using this command I got an error that I need to upgrade a dependency. But If I try to upgrade manually terminal shows me an advice that I'm already using the last version of this package.

```sh
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Also I tried to follow this tutorial, but it is not compatible with my debian version

[docker-ce : Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.3.0) but 2.2.3-3ubuntu3 is to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002345/docker-ce-depends-libseccomp2-2-3-0-but-2-2-3-3ubuntu3-is-to-be-installe)

> Depends: libseccomp2 (>= 2.4.0) but 2.3.3-4 is to be installed

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error. I made the wrong Linux distribution. I had chosen Ubuntu instead of Debian. I had to delete the lines with ubuntu in `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and I did `sudo apt-get update` and I installed `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. It worked for me !